# Final Questions - Part 1 (Poisson Process)

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, poisson-process

After owing a lot to you guys on this website, I finally took my exam on Stochastic Process today! There were some questions in this exam that I was not sure about. I want to share it with you guys and see what you guys think.

This is from my recollection of the exam that I took few hours ago so might not be 100% rigorous. Please understand and let me know if I am missing some details necessary. Of course, for legal issue, this is not completely the same as the exam itself.

> Black birds arrive at the John's office at the according to Poisson Process with parameter $\alpha$. Independently of the black birds, yellow birds arrive at the office according to Poisson Process with parameter $\beta$. Starting from 9:00AM until 10:AM, given that there were 3 black birds and 5 yellow birds arrived at the office, what is the probability that all 3 black birds arrived before 5 yellow birds?

**My answer**:

Unfortunately, I could not solve this question. But I tried my best to guess and gave two solutions:

[Solution 1]

Let $X_i$ ~ Unif($0,1$), $i = 1,2,3$  be the arrival time of the black birds and $Y_k$ ~ Unif($0,1$), $k = 1,2,3,4,5$  be the arrival time of the yellow birds.

Therefore, we calculate:

$\int^{1}_{0} P(max{X_i}<t) \cdot P(min{Y_k}>t) \ dt$

= $\int^{1}_{0} t^3(1-t)^5 \ dt$

Then I could not solve this integral by substitution or integration by parts.

[Solution 2]

$P$($3$ black birds arrived before all $5$ yellow birds) =

$P$(first arrival was black bird) + $P$(second arrival was black bird) + $P$(third arrival was black bird)  =

$\ {3 \choose 1}\frac{\alpha}{3\alpha + 5 \beta} + {2 \choose 1}\frac{\alpha}{2\alpha + 5 \beta} + {1 \choose 1}\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + 5 \beta} $

Is any of the solutions correct? Haha :')