# Final Question - Part 2 (Branching Process $Z_0 = 8$. Find $P(Z_2 =0)$)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Consider a branching process where the number of offspring of an individual is a binomial random variable with parameters (3, p), with $p ∈ (0, 1)$. $Z_0 = 8$. What is $P(Z_2 =0)$

My attempt:

Let $s = P(Z_2 = 0 | Z_0=1)$

s= $P(Z_1=0)  + P(Z_1 = 1, Z_2 = 0) + P(Z_1 = 2, Z_2 = 0)  + P(Z_1 = 3, Z_2 = 0)$

= $(1-p)^3 + 3(p)(1-p)^2(1-p) + 3(p)^2(1-p)(1-p)^2 + 3(p)^3(1-p)^3$

Therefore, if $Z_0 = 8$, $P(Z_2 =0) = s^8 = ((1-p)^3 + 3(p)(1-p)^2(1-p) + 3(p)^2(1-p)(1-p)^2 + 3(p)^3(1-p)^3)^8$

Comment: [Part 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307822/final-questions-part-1-poisson-process)

Comment: [Part 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307844/final-questions-part-3-birth-and-death-process-hardest-and-nastiest-bd-q)

Comment: I think your calculation of the second term in $s$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s = P(Z_2 = 0 | Z_0=1)$, then we have 
\begin{align}
s &= P(Z_1=0| Z_0=1)  + P(Z_1 = 1, Z_2 = 0|Z_0=1) \\&+ P(Z_1 = 2, Z_2 = 0|Z_0=1)  + P(Z_1 = 3, Z_2 = 0|Z_0=1) \\
&= (1-p)^3 + 3(p)(1-p)^2P(Z_2=0|Z_1=1) \\&+ 3(p)^2(1-p)P(Z_2=0|Z_1=2) + (p)^3P(Z_2=0|Z_1=3) \\
&=(1-p)^3 + 3(p)(1-p)^2(1-p)^3 + 3(p)^2(1-p)((1-p)^3)^2 + (p)^3((1-p)^3)^3 \\
&=(1-p)^3+3p(1-p)^5+3p^2(1-p)^7+p^3(1-p)^9 \\
&= (1-p)^3 (1+3p(1-p)^2+3p^2(1-p)^4 + p^3(1-p)^6) \\
&= (1-p)^3 (1+p(1-p)^2)^3 \\
&= [(1-p)(1+p(1-p)^2)]^3
\end{align}

If $Z_0=8$, just raise to the $8$-th power.

$$[(1-p)(1+p(1-p)^2)]^{24}$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 8 individuals, the generating function for the number, $X$, in the next generation is $$\sum_ip(X=i)t^i=(pt+q)^{24}.$$
The probability there are no offspring in the following generation is$$\sum_ip(X=i)q^{3i}=(pq^3+q)^{24}.$$