# Final Questions - Part 3 (Birth and Death Process) - (hardest and nastiest B&D question I have encountered, ever)

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, birth-death-process

> There is a selective group that people can join. Arrival of people who want to join the group is Poisson Process with parameter $\lambda$. The person who arrive at the group can join the group only if he/she gets approval from all existing members. Each member will say 'yes' with probability 1/2 and 'no' with probability 1/2. Also, each member of the group leaves the group independently at a Exponential distribution of time $\mu$. The number of members of this group defines a birth and death process. What is the limiting probability?

My attempt:

I came up with a very nasty answer.

$\alpha_i = \frac{1}{i!}(\frac{1}{2})^{\sum_0^{i-1}i}(\frac{\lambda}{\mu})^i\alpha_0 \ $  for $i = 1,2,3,...$

$\alpha_0 = (1 + \sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i!}(\frac{1}{2})^{\sum_0^{i-1}i}(\frac{\lambda}{\mu})^i\alpha_0 )^{-1}$

Does anyone has any idea if this is correct?

Comment: [Part 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307822/final-questions-part-1-poisson-process)

Comment: [Part 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307833/final-question-part-2-branching-process-z-0-8-find-pz-2-0)

Comment: What is the limiting probability of what?  That a newly arriving person is admitted into the group?  Or the limiting probability distribution of number in group?

Comment: Assuming the latter, your first expression is OK, except that I would further simplify $\left(\frac12\right)^{\sum_0^{i-1} i}$ to $\left(\frac12\right)^{\frac{i(i-1)}{2}}$.

Comment: IIRC, it literally just asked "What is the limiting probability"? So I assumed that they want limiting probability from $\alpha_0$ to $\alpha_\infty$. OMG, I didn't think of doing that. Thanks!

Comment: You have defined $\alpha_0$ in terms of $\alpha_0$. I do not think this will go over well.